# Htaccess Domain Redirects, How Do I Persist Current Page?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, laravel, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have numerous domains, the main domain is `example.com`, and the addon domains are `example1.com`, `example2.com`, `example3.com`.

I would like these domains to all redirect to the main domain, `example.com`.

I can do this with the following code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example1.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example1.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http://example.com" [R=301,L]
```

This would redirect `example1.com` to `example.com`, simple.
However, if I type in `example1.com/products`, the URL does not change, no redirection occurs.

How can I make these addon domains redirect to the main domain and keep the users current location (web directory)?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example1.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.example1.com
RewriteRule (.*) "http://example.com/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This still seems to have the same behaviour, it does the redirection only it adds `index.php` to the end, the specific page is not returned, the home page is returned.  So the final result looks like `example.com/index.php` regardless of what page the user is currently on.

Comment: Remome ^ and $ from condition: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example1.com [OR]

Comment: Exactly the same behaviour @Vasily

Answer (score 0):

Clear your browser cache and try :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [NC,L,R]
```

Comment: Same behaviour as the answer above, redirects to home page and appends `index.php`, thinking this part could be Laravel specific, as further rewrites are handled by the routes file.